# Actual correct limits for Sharepoint Online choice field/column

Tags: sharepoint-online, choice-field, limitations

I researched and tested on SP Online, I was able to add multiple choices (100+) in a single item column and able to store 8K+ choices in the choice field/column.

Is there an actual place where we can find the limit for this field type (not the number of columns but the size limit of the field value and choices)? I mean it for SharePoint Online.

I need to decide a way to add tags to a item which can still be used to filter the list but where you can add tags manually if desired, but never repeated ones.

This can't be done with ootb, cause SP will lock the "enforce unique" if it is multchoice. I will leverage the filtering between out-of-the-box features and custom filtering with SPFX. So this information would be quite important.

Thank you all.

Comment: It is the sum of the column data types that cannot reach greater than 8,000 bytes for a single list, not the number of entries in a [choice] column per se.

Answer (score 0):

Each column type has a size value listed in bytes and it is the sum of all columns in a SharePoint list cannot exceed 8,000 bytes, referring to this document: [Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits#column-limits)

There is no specific limit for number of choices you can have in a single choice column, but it does have a limit of **255 characters** and also

- Choice field maximum size: **30 bytes**
- Choice (multiple selection) field maximum size: **22 bytes**

Comment: I saw that, but this math does not match. Neither the size of 8 kb nor the 255 I test you can put a lot more than that. Maybe is valid for SP 2013 but not sure for Online

Comment: @RicardoSilva This is the Threshold values for all version of SharePoint Server. I don’t think we can have larger numbers in SharePoint Online since the limits Online are much more restrictive technically. 

One more thing, the column limits for SharePoint Online are not in written in official documentations. You might need a ticket open with Microsoft to get that.